# aws sam build failing: property SnapStart not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cold-start

AWS sam build failing after adding SnapStart property in function yaml file.

```
 [InvalidResourceException('MyFunSnapstart', 'property SnapStart not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function'), InvalidResourceException('MyFunLamdaFunSnapstart', 'property SnapStart not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function')] ('MyFunSnapstart', 'property SnapStart not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function') ('MyFunSnapstart', 'property SnapStart not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function')
```

template.yaml file code:

```
  MyFunSnapstart:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: my-lamda-fun
      Handler: com.poc.lambda.handler.MyLambda::handleRequest
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      SnapStart:
        ApplyOn: PublishedVersions
      Events:
        MyEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /api/snapstart/hello
            RestApiId: !Ref MyRestApi
            Method: GET
```

My sam cli version is : SAM CLI, version 1.65.0

Answer (score 2):

SAM CLI actually released version 1.66 around an hour ago with support for this new property: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/tag/v1.66.0 (and [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/aws-sam-cli/#history)), so if you update now it should work correctly.

Comment: I just checked the sam cli release notes and updated to 1.66.0. Build is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: How to publish lambda function through sam template.yaml ? Just putting above configuration doesn't make SnapStart to work

Comment: After you create a version, you need to publish a version. SnapStart works on versions. SAM has a "AutoPublishAlias" property where you specify an alias name, and SAM will publish a version and point an alias to it. That works for SnapStart enabled functions